# How do you get P(A|C) from P(A, B|C)?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability

Is there a way to calculate P(A|C) from P(A, B|C)? I'm guessing that the following will only work when A and B are conditionally independent: P(A, B|C) = P(A|C)P(B|C).

Comment: Ignore the conditioning on $C$ for a moment. How does one in general get a marginal distribution $P(A)$ from a joint distribution $P(A,B)$? One ``integrates out" the dependence on $B$, which, in the case of a discrete probability, just means you sum over all the possible values of $B$, that is $P(A) = \sum_B P(A,B)$. The same principle still holds even if you do it conditionally: $P(A|C) = \sum_B P(A,B|C)$.

Comment: @stats_model Thank you! Just one follow-up. Could you explain to me why the following would be wrong:                                                                                                     $$P(A|C) = \sum_{B}P(A,B|C)P(B)$$                                                                               Or rather when you add $P(B)$, what is getting calculated? I'm having trouble sorting this out.

Comment: Not sure what to say to that last comment other than...its wrong? Maybe you are thinking about similarity to equation (ignoring $C$) $P(A,B) = P(A|B)P(B)$

Comment: The version of that equation that would be right could be $P(A|C) = \sum_B P(A|B,C)P(B|C)$, which is just using the fact that $P(A,B|C) = P(A|B,C)P(B|C)$, which again, is the analogue to the not-conditional-on-$C$ fact that $P(A,B) = P(A|B)P(B)$ as stated above.

Comment: Thank you, @stats_model. What happens in a scenario like this:                                                $$\sum_{B} P(A,B|B,C)P(B) = ?$$

Comment: It's not clear to me that such an expression has any sensible interpretation. Why do you think it does?

Comment: @stats_model This is a simplified version of an equation from a paper. The authors say that $P(A) = \sum_{B}P(A, B|B, C)P(B)$, but I don't see how they get that.

Comment: Why not link to the paper itself and identify the equation within it? The context can help us to explain the intended meaning.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I unfortunately can't share the paper yet.

Comment: The simplifications you’re offering don’t make sense, but it’s unclear whether that’s because the paper—presumably a draft, not an actual paper?—is incorrect or your simplification is incorrect. I’m voting to close this question as “Needs details or clarity”.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I would ask you to reconsider your position. I am asking a mathematical question to check my understanding. I don't understand why $P(A)=\sum_{B}P(A,B|B,C)P(B)$ does not make sense (as you seem to suggest). That's what I'd like help with. Nothing else (e.g., the paper) is relevant.

Comment: @Namenlos I can't agree with your claim that "Nothing else (e.g., the paper) is relevant." In particular, the statement that $P(A) = \sum_B P(A,B|B,C)P(B)$ is patently false (in the first place, I am not entirely sure what is even meant by $B$ being on both sides of the conditioning statement), and it is unclear to myself (and presumably to  others) what might lead one to write such an expression. The context of the paper is thus helpful for sorting these questions out. For example, is the equation a typo? Or is it based on some misunderstanding which context will elucidate?

Comment: @stats_model I was typing too quickly and it's actually supposed to be $P(A|C) = \sum_{B}P(A,B|B,C)P(B)$. Is this also false? I'm interested in understanding why it is false (if it is false).

Comment: The equation still does not make a lot of sense to me. The expression $P(A,B|B,C)$ is quite strange...this expression could be interpreted as $P(A,B|B,C) = P(A|B,C)$, since $P(B|B,C) = 1$, but in that case, why write it in such a redundant/convoluted way? Even ignoring this issue, the expression is _still_ wrong in general.

Comment: @stats_model Can you recommend any reading on conditional probabilities with multiple variables? This isn't something that my probability course went into much detail on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135908/discussion-between-stats-model-and-namenlos).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore the conditioning on $C$ for a moment. How does one in general get a marginal distribution $P(A)$ from a joint distribution $P(A,B)$? One "integrates out" the dependence on $P(B)$, which, in the case of a discrete probability, just means you sum over all the possible values of $B$, that is $P(A) = \sum_B P(A,B)$. The same principle still holds even if you do it conditionally: $P(A|C) = \sum_B P(A,B|C)$. Some equivalent ways of expressing this last sum are possible by factorizing $P(A,B|C)$ further either as $P(A|B,C)P(B|C)$ or as $P(B|A,C)P(A|C)$ (again, these are the conditional analogues of the fact that $P(A,B) = P(A|B)P(B) = P(B|A)P(A)$):
$$P(A|C) = \sum_B P(A,B|C) = \sum_B P(A|B,C)P(B|C) = \sum_B P(B|A,C)P(A|C)$$.

In the comments, there was a question about the equation $P(A|C) = \sum_B P(A,B|B,C)P(B)$. To begin, the expression $P(A,B|B,C)$ is quite strange. Formally, one could interpret it as $P(A,B|B,C) = P(A|B,C)$, since $P(B|B,C) = 1$, but in that case it seems unnatural to write it in such a redundant/convoluted way. Even ignoring this issue, the expression is *still* wrong in general. In general, it is difficult to explain *why* a wrong expression is wrong, since the burden of proof is on the asker to specify why they would think the expression might be true in the first place. However, the following counterexample at least shows that it is indeed wrong. Let $A$ be the result of a biased coin flip which is 1 with probability 1/3, and let $B$ be the result of an independent biased coin flip with $B=1$ with probability 1/3, and let $C$ be the sum of the two flips. Consider now, $P(A=1|C=1)$. Clearly, $C=1$ happens only if $A=1$ and $B=0$ or $B=1$ and $A=0$, so by Bayes's rule, $P(A=1|C=1)=1/2$. On the other hand, we have $P(A=1|B=1,C=1) = 1/3$, $P(A=1|B=0,C=1)= 1$, which implies
$$\sum_B P(A=1|B,C=1)P(B) = \underbrace{P(A=1|B=1,C=1)P(B=1)}_{=0} + \underbrace{P(A=1|B=0,C=1)}_{=1}\underbrace{P(B=1)}_{=1/3} = 1/3 \neq 1/2$$